# XAMPP - Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, errors, shutdown, xampp

Last night MySQL Service on my XAMPP local server was running fine. Today... it starts for 10 seconds and then give me following error:

```
10:14:28 AM  [main]     Initializing Modules
10:14:28 AM  [main]     The FileZilla module is disabled
10:14:28 AM  [main]     The Mercury module is disabled
10:14:28 AM  [main]     Starting Check-Timer
10:14:28 AM  [main]     Control Panel Ready
10:14:31 AM  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...
10:14:31 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: running
10:14:38 AM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL app...
10:14:38 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: running
10:14:49 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
10:14:49 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:14:49 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:14:49 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:14:49 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:14:49 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:14:49 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
10:14:49 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

The Log file follows:

```
2019-11-21 10:14:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-11-21 10:14:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-11-21 10:14:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-11-21 10:14:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-11-21 10:14:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-11-21 10:14:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-11-21 10:14:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-11-21 10:14:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-11-21 10:14:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-11-21 10:14:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '\CoreApps\Mayfield\xampp-rtweek\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-11-21 10:14:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '\CoreApps\Mayfield\xampp-rtweek\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-11-21 10:14:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-11-21 10:14:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.15 started; log sequence number 1604056; transaction id 9
2019-11-21 10:14:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from E:\CoreApps\Mayfield\xampp-rtweek\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-11-21 10:14:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191121 10:14:38
2019-11-21 10:14:38 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-11-21 10:14:38 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Apparently, there doesn't seem to be any error. I have an older version of XAMPP that is workin' fine, which means there is no Port 3306 issue.

I have tried couple of suggested solutions on other platforms, e.g. deleting ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, and ibdata1 files and adding

```
innodb_force_recovery = 4
```

to configuration file, that didn't work for me.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score -2):

first suspect .. the usual - "windows happened" - Wednesday = patchday - there is potential risk that one of the updates "f**ked" things up - and in most cases a simple reboot should do it.

But if you tried with a second mysql server ... make sure that the port is free when you try to start this one the next time.